# Second Monitor goes to Sleep - Won't wake up

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, sleep, power-management

My second monitor goes to "sleep" at random intervals and never wakes up. I have to push the physical off button of the monitor, on, and then i can see stuff again for a few minutes.

- powersave settings are all to OFF incl. PCI
- monitor = ThinkVision L192p 19.0-inch Monitor
- graphics card = build-in Intel Graphics Card (laptop is Toshiba Satellite C660-1DG) (so for clarity not Nvidia of which there are many threads)
- Windows 10
- "when it happens" : this is really weird but it changes, in the beginning mostly directly, then for some weeks after 3 minutes (so i thought i nailed it), but now... after a random amount of minutes, sometimes 0... sometimes 5...or somewhere in between, really weird.
- I have 2 other laptops (lenovo) where it does not happen, so it must be windows10 / intel graphics specific.

The problem is not intermediate, it just always happens.

I think I have tried about everything that can be found on Stackexchange (see "related" on the right hand side and hundreds of threads on toms hardware, reddit, microsoft forums etc...etc ... nogo. So this is my last resort. I'm really looking now into WHY it does this, I could not find specific items in Windows Event Logs.

Comment: how is the second monitor connected?

Comment: It's and older laptop and and an older monitor so via DVI

Comment: First try to detach and reattach the monitor cable on both ends. Verify that shaking the cable gently does not cause the problem. If not, put your computer in standby mode purposefully. Observe the message on your display (in my case it is `No signal on DVI`, yours should be similar). Next time the monitor shuts itself unexpectedly please observe the message - is it the same? If there is no message - monitor just flicks off - the most likely cause is faulty internal power supply on your monitor. You should probably try to have it diagnosed by a service technician. I suspect bad capacitors.